# MySQL returns only one row

Tags: php, mysql

I have this simple PHP code:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `title`, `url_title` FROM `fastsearch` WHERE `tags` LIKE '%$q%' LIMIT 5");
    $query2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($quer);
    print_r($query2);
```

It only returns this:

```
Array ( [title] => Kill Bill Vol 1. [url_title] => kill_bill_vol_1 )
```

I have 3500+ rows in the table, and running the SQL in PhpMyAdmin works perfectly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `title`,
                             `url_title`
                        FROM `fastsearch`
                       WHERE `tags`
                            LIKE '%$q%'
                       LIMIT 5");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

- You misspelled `$query` in your example
- `mysql_fetch_assoc()` will return a row each time it is called, and `FALSE` when out of rows. Use that to your advantage, by assigning a variable to it in the condition. Within the `while()` loop, `$row` will be the current row.

Comment: I'll accept your answer in 3 minutes, when it allows me. I've did use foreach, but i don't know how to do this with while:

Comment: foreach(mysql_fetch_assoc($quer) as $row => $item) {
$arrResults[$row] = $item;
}

I need this, because i'm using with JSON data, with json_encode function.

Comment: @wintercounter The returned value isn't an array how you want it, so I don't think that will work (it will just loop over the members of the first returned row's array).

Answer (score 3):

Right, you are not fetching the results properly.

`mysql_fetch_assoc()` only returns one row at a time.  Use a loop to read all rows.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `title`, `url_title` FROM `fastsearch` WHERE `tags` LIKE '%$q%' LIMIT 5");

$resultSet = array();
while ($cRecord = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  $resultSet[] = $cRecord;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php states:

```
mysql_fetch_assoc — Fetch a result row as an associative array
```

So if you want to iterate over result you have to use a loop e.g.:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["title"];
    echo $row["url_title"];       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` is functions which is fetching multiple records
>   and displaying through print_r().

```
$query = "SELECT `title`, `url_title` FROM `fastsearch` WHERE `tags` LIKE '%$q%' LIMIT 5";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
while(null ! == ($query = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))){
     print_r($query);
}
```

Comment: Please give some explanation of this answer

Answer (score 1):

the method fetch_assoc() returns one row, you need to loop with it