# MySQL WHERE IN issue

Tags: mysql, where-clause

DOH!  It's now resolved:

HUMAN ERROR:  Helps if I iterate through the data as everyone has suggested below...added the following code to loop through the results...

```
while ($rowprevprev = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultprevprev)) {
            print_r($rowprevprev);
        }
```

[Hangs head in shame....suitably embarassed...]

Cheers everyone!

H.

Hi,

Have a simply piece of code (thanks to an earlier posting):

```
SELECT
  AVG (q1) AS q1, AVG (q2) AS q2, AVG (q3) AS q3, AVG (q4) AS q4,
  AVG (q5) AS q5, AVG (q6) AS q6, AVG (q7) AS q7, AVG (q8) AS q8,
  AVG (q9) AS q9, AVG (q10) AS q10, AVG (q11) AS q11, AVG (q12) AS q12,
  AVG (q13) AS q13, AVG (q14) AS q14, AVG (q15) AS q15, AVG (q16) AS q16,
  AVG (q17) AS q17, AVG (q18) AS q18, AVG (q19) AS q19, AVG (q20) AS q20,
  AVG (q21) AS q21, AVG (q22) AS q22
FROM thotels_results
WHERE brand IN ('XYZ','ABC','EFG')
AND date = 'NOV2010' GROUP BY brand;
```

The output using a query browser is:

```
q1       q2       q3       q4       q5       q6       q7       q8       q9       q10      q11      q12      q13      q14      q15      q16      q17      q18      q19      q20      q21      q22
8.1724   8.2414   8.2414   7.8966   8.5862   8.5517   9.0000   8.5862   8.1724   7.9655   8.8966   8.6207   8.2414   8.3793   7.8276   8.3793   7.9310   8.4138   8.6897   8.3448   8.8621   8.5172
8.7714   8.8429   8.1643   8.7500   8.7571   8.9000   9.4071   9.1214   8.5714   8.7643   9.5143   8.9429   9.1643   8.9857   7.9500   8.9286   8.7000   9.0429   9.0143   8.7214   9.1214   9.3071
8.6009   8.5686   7.8528   8.3133   8.3423   8.6410   9.0301   8.6912   8.3233   8.3389   9.2029   8.3969   8.6856   8.5017   7.8071   8.4816   8.3512   8.6789   8.6789   8.3913   8.6388   8.8986
```

When I **VAR_DUMP**, however, I get the following, it would appear not all the data is there:

```
array
  0 => string '8.1724' (length=6)
  'q1' => string '8.1724' (length=6)
  1 => string '8.2414' (length=6)
  'q2' => string '8.2414' (length=6)
  2 => string '8.2414' (length=6)
  'q3' => string '8.2414' (length=6)
  3 => string '7.8966' (length=6)
  'q4' => string '7.8966' (length=6)
  4 => string '8.5862' (length=6)
  'q5' => string '8.5862' (length=6)
  5 => string '8.5517' (length=6)
  'q6' => string '8.5517' (length=6)
  6 => string '9.0000' (length=6)
  'q7' => string '9.0000' (length=6)
  7 => string '8.5862' (length=6)
  'q8' => string '8.5862' (length=6)
  8 => string '8.1724' (length=6)
  'q9' => string '8.1724' (length=6)
  9 => string '7.9655' (length=6)
  'q10' => string '7.9655' (length=6)
  10 => string '8.8966' (length=6)
  'q11' => string '8.8966' (length=6)
  11 => string '8.6207' (length=6)
  'q12' => string '8.6207' (length=6)
  12 => string '8.2414' (length=6)
  'q13' => string '8.2414' (length=6)
  13 => string '8.3793' (length=6)
  'q14' => string '8.3793' (length=6)
  14 => string '7.8276' (length=6)
  'q15' => string '7.8276' (length=6)
  15 => string '8.3793' (length=6)
  'q16' => string '8.3793' (length=6)
  16 => string '7.9310' (length=6)
  'q17' => string '7.9310' (length=6)
  17 => string '8.4138' (length=6)
  'q18' => string '8.4138' (length=6)
  18 => string '8.6897' (length=6)
  'q19' => string '8.6897' (length=6)
  19 => string '8.3448' (length=6)
  'q20' => string '8.3448' (length=6)
  20 => string '8.8621' (length=6)
  'q21' => string '8.8621' (length=6)
  21 => string '8.5172' (length=6)
  'q22' => string '8.5172' (length=6)
```

The **VAR_DUMP** appears to only bring back the first row of the query and not all three rows.  I need to access all three rows of data so I can perform a calculation.

Anyone with any ideas and/or suggestions?

Thanks,

Homer.

Comment: Are you doing this via PHP?  If so, can you show the code that you are using?  It sounds like you are just grabbing one row at a time with something like fetch_assoc, in which case VAR_DUMP will only display one row.

Comment: maybe you dont retrieve all the lines. Check if you dont do something like mysql_fetch_row() (which retrieves only one row). `VAR_DUMP appears to only bring back` - var_dump doesn't bring back anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not var_dump that's the problem, it's the code you're using to fetch data from MySQL. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372197/mysql-returns-only-one-row) from yesterday - I think you're making the same mistake.

Answer (score 1):

well if you're using php,

```
    $query = mysql_query("do your select query here");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```