# SQL. Column MAX

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

Ok, So i have 3 Tables:
Movies (**Movienum**, Title, Yearreleased)
Actsin (*Movienum*, *StarID*)
Stars  (**StarID**, Givenname, Familyname)

- Bold for primary key, italics of foreign

Now I have to find the most recent film Eddie Murphy has starred in and here is my attempt:

```
SELECT M.Title, M.Yearreleased
FROM Movies M
WHERE M.Yearreleased = (
    SELECT MAX(M.Yearreleased)
    FROM Stars S, ActsIn A, Movies M  
    WHERE S.Givenname = 'Eddie' AND S.Familyname = 'Murphy'
    AND S.StarID = A.StarID
    AND A.MovieNum = M.MovieNum);
```

This returns all the movies from the same year as the last Eddie Murphy film.

Any help would be amazing :D

Comment: actually, if Murphy has starred in several movies this year, you can't get exactly last one movie but all the movies with Murphy released last year.  You have to store date released.

Comment: is this homework? Sounds very similar to an Oracle question...

Comment: Its for Uni.  The only movies for murphy in the DB are from 3 seperate years.

Comment: Well for oracle use WHERE ROWNUM <= 1, I added a link to my answer as well, for returning X rows for whatever SQL type you are using.

Comment: all sorted thanks for you link :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can

```
ORDER BY Yearrealesed DESC
```

And if you want just one then `LIMIT 1`

[Link to ORDER BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html)

**EDIT:** I Saw you can't use LIMIT, you may wanna check out this old post. (It may help)

[Old Post using  fetch_assoc()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372197/mysql-returns-only-one-row)

Also it now appears you aren't using MYSQL. Here is another link, that shoudl give an answer for whatever type of SQL you are using.

[Return only X amount of rows](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/59.cfm)

Comment: that second link :D:D:D:D.  Thank you so much.  it was SELECT first yada yada yada.  Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
SELECT M.Title, M.Yearreleased
FROM Stars S, ActsIn A, Movies M  
WHERE S.Givenname = 'Eddie' AND S.Familyname = 'Murphy'
AND S.StarID = A.StarID
AND A.MovieNum = M.MovieNum
ORDER BY Yearreleased Desc
LIMIT 1
```

Also, on an not so related note, I would consider start using explicit joins, instead of implicit joins. That would make it look like this:

```
SELECT M.Title, M.Yearreleased
FROM Stars S
INNER JOIN ActsIn A on S.StarID = A.StarID
INNER JOIN Movies M on A.MovieNum = M.MovieNum
WHERE S.Givenname = 'Eddie' AND S.Familyname = 'Murphy'
ORDER BY Yearreleased Desc
LIMIT 1
```

Trust me, explicit `JOIN` will make you free when outer joins are needed. And the query is better understandable and readable: joins are joins, filters are filters

Comment: unfortunately LIMIT is not supported by the DBMS I have to use for uni. which is :(.

Comment: SQLFIRE.  it give me this error " Token Unknown - LIMIT" cheers for the tip on explicit joins :)

Comment: Your tag said mySQL, which LIMIT x is a valid clause in.  If you are using Microsoft SQL, you can use TOP x instead....  (Select top 1 ...)