# Mysql result and php result is not same why?

Tags: php, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL returns only one row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372197/mysql-returns-only-one-row)

**In Terminal**

```
mysql> select image,title,price from test;
```

db result:

```
image title price
 1       2     3
 4       5     6
```

**But, In PHP**

```
.
.
$query=mysql_query("select image,title, price from test",$connect);

$row=mysql_fetch_object($query);

print json_encode($row);
```

result:

```
image= 1, title = 2  , price=3
```

why don't print image=4  title=5 price=6?
how?

Comment: sorry for not to aceept . I did't know how to accept the answer. I will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the PHP documentation for [`mysql_fetch_object()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php), its purpose is to "Fetch **a** result row as an object."  You have to keep calling  until there are no more rows:

```
$result = mysql_query("select image,title, price from test", $connect);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    print json_encode($row);
}
mysql_free_result($result);
```

Also notice I renamed the return value of `mysql_query()` to `$result`, as that's a bit more correct.

Comment: this time  Only print image=4, title=5, price=6     don't print image=1 title=2  price=3 why??

Comment: I'm not sure - is the row still in the database? Try running it again? This is a straightforward code sequence that is in use in many, many PHP scripts.

Answer (score 3):

Because you are only printing the first $row

You need a loop:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the query in a while loop:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query ))
{
print json_encode($row);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_fetch_object` fetches only a single row. You need to loop through them until there are no more rows, like this:

```
while (($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)) !== false) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[mysql_fetch_object](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_object) method returns only first row of result set. You should iterate through result set to get all rows.