# $_GET id from url displays only first record from database PHP mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, get

I am trying to get id from url "/view.php?postID=2", having this code:

```
$post = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE postID='$postID'";
$post1 = mysql_query($post);
$postV = mysql_fetch_array($post1);
$postID = $postV['postID'];
$postImg = $postV['img'];
$postTitle = $postV['title'];
$postAuthor = $postV['author'];
$postDate = $postV['date'];
$postCategory = $postV['category'];
$postText = $postV['text'];


<?php
if (isset($_GET['postID'])) {
    $newsID = $_GET['postID'];
}

echo "<section class='view_news'>
    <img class='view_newsimg' src='$postImg'>
    <h3 class='lath'>$postTitle</h3>
    <ul class='det'>
        <li class='adc'>avtori: $postAuthor</li>
        <li class='adc'>TariRi: $postDate</li>
        <li class='adc'>kategoria: $postCategory</li>
    </ul>
    <p class='news'>
        $postText
    </p>
</section>";
?>
```

but it only shows data from the array where postID = 1

can anybody tell me what to do? Thanks :)

Comment: See also [MySQL returns only one row](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4372197), and as usual [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)

Comment: @mano That's not his question. The URL contains `?postID=2`, but his query is returning `postID = 1`.

Comment: Where do you set `$postID` before performing the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
$post = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE postID='$postID'";
```

with that:

```
$post = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE postID='{$_GET['postID']}'";
```

Comment: Or simply set `$postID = $_GET['postID']` first.

Answer (score 1):

Three things are wrong here:

1. You need to get postID value first using $_GET

   $post = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE postID='{$_GET['$postID']}";
2. You should use while loop

   while($postV = mysql_fetch_array($post1)) {

   $postID = $postV['postID'];

   $postImg = $postV['img'];

   $postTitle = $postV['title'];

   $postAuthor = $postV['author'];

   $postDate = $postV['date'];

   $postCategory = $postV['category'];
   $postText = $postV['text'];
   }
3. Your code is vunerable to SQL injection, use mysql_real_escape_string() to prevent it.

Comment: How will this solve the problem that it's returning the record for the wrong ID?

Comment: If `postID` is a unique key, he doesn't need a loop.

Answer (score 0):

There are three things you are doing wrong here. First you are running `mysql_query()` before setting up `$postID` and the other is you are not using While loop. The third thing is that you are starting php two times `<?php`. Try setting `$postID` and using while loop. Your code should look like this

```
    <?php
$postID="Your Value";
            post = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE postID='$postID'";
            $post1 = mysql_query($post);
    while($postV = mysql_fetch_array($post1){

            $postID = $postV['postID'];
            $postImg = $postV['img'];
            $postTitle = $postV['title'];
            $postAuthor = $postV['author'];
            $postDate = $postV['date'];
            $postCategory = $postV['category'];
            $postText = $postV['text'];
            }


            if (isset($_GET['postID'])) {
                $newsID = $_GET['postID'];
            }

            echo "<section class='view_news'>
                <img class='view_newsimg' src='$postImg'>
                <h3 class='lath'>$postTitle</h3>
                <ul class='det'>
                    <li class='adc'>avtori: $postAuthor</li>
                    <li class='adc'>TariRi: $postDate</li>
                    <li class='adc'>kategoria: $postCategory</li>
                </ul>
                <p class='news'>
                    $postText
                </p>
            </section>";
            ?>
```

Hope this helps you