# parse json from php display with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

I have a 2 part question. In PHP, I use `fetch_assoc` like in the answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372197/mysql-returns-only-one-row) which returns an array of objects. Then my JS is:

```
var result = JSON.parse(response),
    output = "";
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
    var obj = result[i];
    output += "<div class='mysql_row'>";
    for (key in obj){
        output += "<div class='mysql_col'>" + obj.key. + "</div>";
    }
    output += "</div>";
}
document.getElementById('main_grid').innerHTML = output;
```

I read in another post that using "key" should give me the value, but I'm getting `undefined` even though logging to the console gives me an array of strings.

1. Am I doing something wrong with my for..in?
2. I'm not too experienced with PHP, is there a more elegant way to `echo` and display the data?
   My PHP code:

   ```
   $load = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `role` = 2");
   $emp_proj = array();
   while ($row = $load->fetch_assoc()){
       $emp_proj[] = $row;
   };
   echo json_encode($emp_proj);
   ```

Comment: Are you using `echo json_encode($array);` on the server to return a JSON object? Also perform `console.log(response);` what does it show you?

Comment: the result is [{key1: value},{key1: value}]

Comment: @Zack You must use 8 spaces to indent while code is in a list.

Comment: Still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong with my code though :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not `obj.key` which gives you the value you want, but `obj[key]`:

```
var result = JSON.parse(response),
    output = "";
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
    var obj = result[i];
    output += "<div class='mysql_row'>";
    for (key in obj){
        output += "<div class='mysql_col'>" + obj[key] + "</div>";
    }
    output += "</div>";
}
document.getElementById('main_grid').innerHTML = output;
```

`obj.key` is looking at the object `obj` and retrieving a property whose key is the string `"key"`. `obj[key]` retrieves a property whose name is the value of the variable `key`.

```
var obj = {
    key: 5,
    username: "test"
};

var key = "username";
console.log(obj.key); // 5
console.log(obj[key]); // "test"
console.log(obj.username); // "test"
console.log(obj["username"]); // "test"
```